# op-amp ramp circuit gives half voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, breadboard

I have breadboarded out this circuit and it worked perfectly once. I tried to transfer it stripboard and I have had so success with it again. The schematic is below.

[image]

The description of the circuit can be [found here](http://www.edn.com/design/analog/4314544/Integrator-ramps-up-down-holds-output-level#id1676356-67-a)

The theory of the circuit is to ramp up slowly at power on, maintain close to VCC and ramp down at power off. R1 is supposed to adjust the output voltage, this will always be Vcc so I have just put a 1kΩ resistor here. I have put a 1MΩ in R2. When I do this the output of pin 7 goes straight to 2.75v. If I put a lower value in, around 300k it ramps slowly to around 2.75v (supply is 5v).

Here is my Breadboard.

[image]

I am coming to the conclusion that maybe I have cooked the chip as I am not able to reproduce the required result.

Comment: check your IC by just making Schmitt trigger oscillator and output pin connect to LED, so it will tell you your circuit is proper or not??

Answer (score 1):

If your chip is ok, then it is probably a "slew rate" problem. That is, you have to check if your opamp is able to follow the ramp. Try with a lower frequency signal, which implies a smaller slope in the ramp.